# How do remove a project in qt creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

When I right click a project, the "Remove project" menu is disabled. Why?

I tried to remove the .pro file which gave me a confusing result.

- First I got a message that I could not remove it.
- Then I got a dialog asking if I also wanted to remove it from version control.
- Finally, I got a messge that the file was gone, clicking it confirmed its non existence, it is still visible in the "projects" treeview however.

Comment: I recommend reading http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-managing.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682723/remove-projects-from-qt-creator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't remove a project. You close it: File menu->Close Project. You can then delete the file or do whatever you want. I suggest that you acquaint yourself with qmake sufficiently to be able to manually create project files. They are really simple. A project file for a widgets-based project is quite trivial:

```
QT = widgets
CONFIG += c++11
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp mywidget.cpp
HEADERS += mywidget.h
```

Comment: So why is there a "Remove project" menu item?

Comment: That's for when you're removing a subproject from a project. It's not used to close projects.

Comment: Ok, it should read "remove subproject" then, I suppose. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

go to File>recent projects>clear menu. DONE!