# Is it possible to delete a project from within Qt creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator 3.3.2 and I wonder if it is possible to completely delete a project from within the Creator. Of course I could use my windows explorer and manually delete the files, but for convenience I would like to do it from the IDE. Is it possible?

The closest I could find is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682723/remove-projects-from-qt-creator), but if I understand it correctly it is about removing the project from Qt Creator while keeping the source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such feature. You can ask to delete a specific file of your project by right-clicking it in the project explorer, but you can't delete a whole project, you'll have to do it from your OS's file browser.

Comment: as I didnt find anything, I was expecting this, just wasnt 100% sure. Is it maybe possible that there is a plugin that offers this function?

Comment: Maybe, but I doubt. The plugin won't bring that much as it's farly easy to do it from the file browser. It may also be hard to do from QtCreator which may be using the project folder as working directory

Comment: Actually there is. File - Open File or Project, then navigate to the project folder and delete it. No need to launch explorer, you can do that from a Creator dialog ;)

Comment: @dtech, doesn't "navigate to the project folder" open an explorer?

Comment: Nope, that's an application dialog ;) It doesn't seem to launch an explorer process either, unlike actually launching an explorer. Frankly, I can't think of much software that can actually delete files, and frankly, that is a good thing, as it reduces the possibility of accidentally deleting stuff. I have a media player that can delete files, I learned about that feature the bad way :)

Comment: @dtech I still have to delete the project folder and the build folder, which was the reason I was looking for a feature that would automatically delete all related files

Comment: @tobi303 - you can delete the build folder by Build - Clean. Well, kinda, it doesn't delete the actual folder, just its content. If you don't use shadow build it will put the build in the project folder, so you kill 2 birds with one stone.

Comment: @dtech that only deletes some of the files, but the folder is still present. btw netbeans has the feature I am looking for. There "Delete" removes the project from the IDE and you can check a checkbox to also delete the sources.

Comment: well, I am fine with deleting the stuff manually, just wanted to be sure that there isnt an easier way, because I am about to clean my project folder with hundres of unfinished and old projects

Comment: Cool but not that useful feature, you could do a feature request, generally those for Creator have a much higher chance to get implemented than those about the framework. I personally find the lack of "save project as" as more urgent.